# Expected value of $R^2$ for univariate regression

Tags: regression, univariate

I'm trying to solve the following: Given a standard one-variable linear regression model $$y = \beta_1 x + \beta_0 + \epsilon$$ where $\beta_1, \beta_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\epsilon\sim N(0, \sigma^2)$ with $n$ sample data points $X\in\mathbb{R}^n$, how to calculate the expected value of $R^2$? Thanks!

WLOG, assume the model has no bias. $$y = \beta x + \epsilon$$
$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{X^T Y}{X^T X} = \frac{\beta ||X||^2 + X^T\epsilon}{||X||^2}$$
$$\hat{Y} = \hat{\beta}X = \beta X + \frac{X^T\epsilon X}{||X||^2}$$

$$SST = ||Y - \bar{Y}||^2$$
$$SSR = ||\hat{Y} - \bar{Y}||^2$$
$$R^2 = \frac{SSR}{SST}$$

But the denominator has randomized part, so I can't use linearity to solve this problem?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Just added what I've tried!

Comment: First, I don't think removing $\beta_0$ is "WLOG"!  Keeping or removing $\beta_0$ would have essential impact on the range of $R^2$.  Second, in either case, the expected value of $R^2$ probably doesn't have a closed-form.

Comment: Knowing, or suspecting, that the F-ratio statistic might be involved (as suggested by most regression output), including the terms "F ratio distribution" in a [Web search about regression](https://www.google.com/search?q=F+ratio+distribution+regression) is fruitful.  The duplicate is the top hit.

Comment: @whuber I also suspected that OP probably confused the concepts of $R^2$ and $F$-statistic, of which both denominators and numerators are different.